# Need help with Mesa3D and updating OpenGL

Tags: drivers, updates, graphics, opengl, mesa

The issue here is that I've been trying to update my OpenG* trough Mesa3D, I recently installed Mesa 10.6.7 successfully trough a package from Mesa3D official page (It was a pain to build the whole library to successfully `./configure` it and then install it). But when I check with the commands I get these:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center    
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ironlake Mobile
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 10.3.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 10.3.2
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.16
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

So, I don't know what I made wrong, I have all the possible libraries and packages I need, but still my OS apparently does not update or upgrade after the long process of installing the package of Mesa-10.6.7.

Please help!